# Laravel redirect back to original destination after login

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-4

This seems like a pretty basic flow, and `Laravel` has so many nice solutions for basic things, I feel like I'm missing something.

A user clicks a link that requires authentication.  Laravel's *auth* filter kicks in and routes them to a login page.  User logs in, then goes to the original page they were trying to get to before the 'auth' filter kicked in.

Is there a good way to know what page they were trying to get to originally?  Since Laravel is the one intercepting the request, I didn't know if it keeps track somewhere for easy routing after the user logs in.

If not, I'd be curious to hear how some of you have implemented this manually.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

### For Laravel 5.3 and above

Check [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39595605/908579) below.

### For Laravel 5 up to 5.2

Simply put,

On auth middleware:

```php
// redirect the user to "/login"
// and stores the url being accessed on session
if (Auth::guest()) {
    return redirect()->guest('login');
}
return $next($request);
```

On login action:

```php
// redirect the user back to the intended page
// or defaultpage if there isn't one
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    return redirect()->intended('defaultpage');
}
```

### For Laravel 4 (old answer)

At the time of this answer there was no official support from the framework itself. Nowadays you can use <del>the method pointed out by bgdrl below</del> this method: *(I've tried updating his answer, but it seems he won't accept)*

On auth filter:

```php
// redirect the user to "/login"
// and stores the url being accessed on session
Route::filter('auth', function() {
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        return Redirect::guest('login');
    }
});
```

On login action:

```php
// redirect the user back to the intended page
// or defaultpage if there isn't one
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    return Redirect::intended('defaultpage');
}
```

### For Laravel 3 (even older answer)

You could implement it like this:

```php
Route::filter('auth', function() {
    // If there's no user authenticated session
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        // Stores current url on session and redirect to login page
        Session::put('redirect', URL::full());
        return Redirect::to('/login');
    }
    if ($redirect = Session::get('redirect')) {
        Session::forget('redirect');
        return Redirect::to($redirect);
    }
});
```

```php
// on controller
public function get_login()
{
    $this->layout->nest('content', 'auth.login'); 
}

public function post_login()
{
    $credentials = [
        'username' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    ];

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return Redirect::to('logged_in_homepage_here');
    }

    return Redirect::to('login')->with_input();
}
```

Storing the redirection on Session has the benefit of persisting it even if the user miss typed his credentials or he doesn't have an account and has to signup.

This also allows for anything else besides Auth to set a redirect on session and it will work magically.

Comment: Looks good, although I don't quite get the flow.  User goes to /admin, auth filter grabs it, sets the redirect url in the session and hands off to the login redirect.  Login redirect goes to a page with a form.  Form is submitted, LoginController does an Auth:attempt.  If successful, how do I get back to the auth filter to do the redirect that you have listed?  Would I be better off putting the second if statement (above) in the LoginController after a successful Auth:attempt?

Comment: When Auth::attempt() passes, you can simply redirect the user to the default page (usually his home). That redirection will pass through that filter again and it will redirect him to the original requested URL if there's one. Otherwise, it will simply continue rendering his home. I'll put an example of login action.

Comment: Makes sense, I like that idea.  Gives a default place to drop them, in case they were at the login screen (not via the auth filter), but overrides it if they were headed somewhere else when the auth filter kicked in.  Thanks again Vinicius, a very elegant solution.

Comment: I need to point out that the logic in your answer is not correct. The way you have it, once the user logs in it will always redirect to logged_in_homepage_here.

Comment: Unless you are redirecting to a page that doesn't pass through the auth filter (which isn't a logged_in_homepage, btw), this works perfectly fine and I'm using the exact same approach on 4 projects. In that case, you can always separate the redirection logic on another filter that gets applied to all your routes.

Comment: I tried this and like I said, the way your filter is set up it will never work because once a user hits the login theyll always redirect to the url specified in your controller. The only way to have your use case work is that second if statement from your filter needs to be within the auth::attempt if statement.

Comment: If you are so sure my solution doesn't work, I gently ask you to provide a better answer properly explaining your choices and why it doesn't work. If you are not so sure, feel free to open another question with your code and I'll answer it. Because I'm even more sure that you didn't properly read my previous comment or didn't even try it. Anyway, these comments are going to far.

Comment: If Auth::attempt succeeds, it will always go to that "home_page" default url. There's no way that the auth filter code be executed after control goes into the Auth::attempt. So, the second part code in the filter should go inside the Auth::attempt

Comment: Mate, if auth::attempt is successful, your application will redirect the user. Redirects are completely separate request, so all filters are going to be executed again. You should try it before stating it won't work.

Comment: No change needed on `Route::filter('guest', function()
{
 if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
 //if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});` at `filters.php` page. Just `return Redirect::intended('/');` on controller enough with my Laravel4 app.

Comment: If the user is not logged in i redirect to getLogin (form) if form is filled i submit to postLogin.If I use return Redirect::intended() in that postForm it is redirecting to getLogin, how can i make it redirect to the page before the getlogin

Comment: in 5.1 it's in middleware RedirectIfAuthenticated.php:  if ($this->auth->check()) { return redirect('/privatepage');  }

Comment: In the 5.1 this is done by laravel itself, see https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L85

Comment: thank you so much.you saved my world. the trick was return Redirect::intended('defaultpage');  definitely a +1

Answer (score 105):

## Laravel >= 5.3

The Auth changes in 5.3 make implementation of this a little easier, and slightly different than 5.2 since the Auth Middleware has been moved to the service container.

#### Modify the new Middleware auth redirector

```
/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php
```

Change the handle function slightly, so it looks like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect()->intended('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

#### TL;DR explanation

The only difference is in the 4th line; by default it looks like this:

```
return redirect("/home");
```

Since Laravel >= 5.3 automatically saves the last "intended" route when checking the Auth Guard, it changes to:

```
return redirect()->intended('/home');
```

That tells Laravel to redirect to the last intended page before login, otherwise go to "/home" or wherever you'd like to send them by default.

There's not much out there on the differences between 5.2 and 5.3, and in this area in particular there are quite a few.

Comment: for Laravel 6.4 this is not working anymore... any idea pls?

Comment: I'd use `return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);` to keep your home path in one place.

Comment: But before that, Laravel shows a 403 error page without any action. Instead, how to redirect automatically to the login page, and then to the intended page??

Comment: Thanks. Confirming that it still works for Laravel 9.

Answer (score 29):

I found those two great methods that might be extremely helpful to you.

```
Redirect::guest();
Redirect::intended();
```

You can apply this filter to the routes that need authentication.

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) {
           return Redirect::guest('login');
    }
});
```

What this method basically does it's to store the page you were trying to visit and it is redirects you to the *login* page.

When the user is authenticated you can call

```
return Redirect::intended();
```

and it's redirects you to the page you were trying to reach at first.

It's a great way to do it although I usually use the below method.

```
Redirect::back()
```

*You can check [this](http://toddish.co.uk/blog/laravel-4-session-redirect-urls/) awesome blog.*

Comment: This is much better than the solutions above.  The above solutions require being able to pass a closure to the login function which I couldn't do with 4.1.  But this was much simpler and worked as is.

Comment: But before that, Laravel shows a 403 error page without any action. Instead, how to redirect automatically to the login page, and then to the intended page??

Answer (score 22):

You may use **Redirect::intended** function. It will redirect the user to the URL they were trying to access before being caught by the authenticaton filter. A fallback URI may be given to this
method in case the intended destinaton is not available.

In post login/register:

```
return Redirect::intended('defaultpageafterlogin');
```

Comment: But before that, Laravel shows a 403 error page without any action. Instead, how to redirect automatically to the login page, and then to the intended page??

Answer (score 14):

Change your LoginControllers constructor to:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        session(['url.intended' => url()->previous()]);
        $this->redirectTo = session()->get('url.intended');

        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
```

It will redirect you back to the page BEFORE the login page (2 pages back).

Comment: The only one that works for me. It must mean I have another redirect happening somewhere but who knows where.

Comment: Out of all above solutions, it worked for me for Laravel 7. Awesome buddy !

Answer (score 12):

I have been using this for a while on my language selector code. As long as you only need to go back by just 1 page it works fine:

```
return Redirect::to(URL::previous());
```

It ain't the most powerful solution out there but it is super-easy and can help solve a few puzzles. :)

Comment: Yes previous() works fine. But if your first login effort fails (so 'login failed' page becomes your previous page) and second login effort succeeds then you are redirected to login page again (which may redirect you to home page).

Comment: Awesome buddy! It helped me to save time.

Answer (score 10):

## For Laravel 8

Following approach works for me for Laravel 8.

### Controller based approach

```
/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthenticatedSessionController.php
```

#### Pre-login

The intended url will be stored in the session at create :

```
/**
 * Display the login view.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function create()
{
    session(['url.intended' => url()->previous()]);
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

#### Post-login

Upon successful login, in case a intended url is available in session then redirect to it otherwise redirect to the default one :

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming authentication request.
 *
 * @param  \App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $request->authenticate();

    //in case intended url is available
    if (session()->has('url.intended')) {
        $redirectTo = session()->get('url.intended');
        session()->forget('url.intended');
    }

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    if ($redirectTo) {
        return redirect($redirectTo);
    }
    return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
return Redirect::intended('/');
```

this will redirect you to default page of your project i.e. start page.

Answer (score 6):

For laravel 5.* try these.

```
return redirect()->intended('/');
```

or

```
return Redirect::intended('/');
```

Answer (score 5):

## Laravel 3

I tweaked your (Vinícius Fragoso Pinheiro) code slightly, and placed the following in filters.php

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    // If there's no user authenticated session
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        // Flash current url to session and redirect to login page
        Session::flash('redirect', URL::full());
        return Redirect::guest('login');
    }
});
```

And then within the my AuthController.php:

```
// Try to log the user in.
if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {

    if ($redirect = Session::get('redirect')) {
        return Redirect::to($redirect);
    } else {
        // Redirect to homepage
        return Redirect::to('your_default_logged_in_page')->with('success', 'You have logged in successfully');
    }
} else {
    // Reflash the session data in case we are in the middle of a redirect 
    Session::reflash('redirect');

    // Redirect to the login page.
    return Redirect::to('login')->withErrors(['password' => 'Password invalid'])->withInput(Input::except('password'));
}
```

Notice that the `'redirect'` session data is reflashed if there is a authentication issue. This keeps the redirect intact during any login mishaps, but should the user click away at any point, the next login process is not disrupted by the session data.

You also need to reflash the data at the point of showing the login form in your `AuthController`, otherwise the chain is broken:

```
public function showLogin()
{
    // Reflash the session data in case we are in the middle of a redirect 
    Session::reflash('redirect');

    // Show the login page
    return View::make('auth/login');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Redirect;`

Then use this:

```
return Redirect::back();
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Laravel 5.8**

**in App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController add the following method**

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    if(!session()->has('url.intended'))
        {
            session(['url.intended' => url()->previous()]);
        }
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

**in App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated replace " return redirect('/home'); " with the following**

```
 if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) 
    {
        return redirect()->intended();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for 5.1. I needed someone to click a "Like" button on a post, get redirected to login, then return to the original page. If they were already logged in, the `href` of the "Like" button was intercepted with JavaScript and turned into an AJAX request.

The button is something like `<a href="/like/931">Like This Post!</a>`. `/like/931` is handled by a LikeController that requires the `auth` middleware.

In the Authenticate middleware (the `handle()` function), add something like this at the start:

```
    if(!str_contains($request->session()->previousUrl(), "/auth/login")) {
        $request->session()->put('redirectURL', $request->session()->previousUrl());
        $request->session()->save();
    }
```

Change `/auth/login` to whatever your URL is for logging in. This code saves the original page's URL in the session unless the URL is the login URL. This is required because it *appears* as though this middleware gets called twice. I am not sure why or if that's true. But if you don't check for that conditional, it will be equal to the correct original page, and then somehow get chanced to `/auth/login`. There is probably a more elegant way to do this.

Then, in the `LikeController` or whatever controller you have that handles the URL for the button pushed on the original page:

```
//some code here that adds a like to the database
//...
return redirect($request->session()->get('redirectURL'));
```

This method is super simple, doesn't require overriding any existing functions, and works great. It is possible there is some easier way for Laravel to do this, but I am not sure what it is. Using the `intended()` function doesn't work in my case because the LikeController needed to also know what the previous URL was to redirect back to it. Essentially two levels of redirection backwards.

Answer (score 0):

For **Laravel 5.5** and probably 5.4

In **App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated** change `redirect('/home')` to `redirect()->intended('/home')` in the handle function:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect()->intended('/home');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

in **App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController** create the `showLoginForm()` function as follows:

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    if(!session()->has('url.intended'))
    {
        session(['url.intended' => url()->previous()]);
    }
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

This way if there was an intent for another page it will redirect there otherwise it will redirect home.

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel now supports this feature out-of-the-box!**
(I believe since 5.5 or earlier).

Add a `__construct()` method to your `Controller` as shown below:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

After login, your users will then be redirected to the page they intended to visit initially.

You can also add Laravel's email verification feature as required by your application logic:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
}
```

The documentation contains a very brief example:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#protecting-routes

It's also possible to choose which controller's methods the middleware applies to by using `except`  or `only` options.

Example with `except`:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
}
```

Example with `only`:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
}
```

More information about `except` and `only` middleware options:

- https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerMiddlewareOptions.html#method_except

Answer (score 0):

if you are using axios or other AJAX javascript library you may want to retrive the url and pass to the front end

you can do that with the code below

```
   $default = '/';

   $location = $request->session()->pull('url.intended', $default);

    return ['status' => 200, 'location' => $location];
```

This will return a json formatted string

Answer (score 0):

Its September 2022 now, and I would like to share what I did for the OP's questions. Please be easy on me, still noob here. 
My problem : After I implement `MustVerifyEmail`, the above solutions did not work. I use Laravel 6.x. 
So after getting headache overnight, countless mugs of coffe, finally its working now. It isn't new solution because it is a modification from previous answers. 
Step 1. 
Do realize that : session with name `'url.intended'` is already been taken by : `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector.php` 
So I choose to use different name for the session which is : `'url_intended'` 
Step 2. 
Add this line:

```
session(['url_intended' => url()->previous()]);
```

In app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php something like below:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        session(['url_intended' => url()->previous()]);
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Now, here comes the key solution. Instead modifying the `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` or `app\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`
which did not work for me, I modify the `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified.php`
by adding the following (copy paste and slight modification from above previous answers)

```
if (session()->has('url_intended')) {
    $redirectURL = session()->get('url_intended');
    session()->forget('url_intended');
    return redirect($redirectURL);
}
```

with full code as below :

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Auth\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class EnsureEmailIsVerified
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $redirectToRoute
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $redirectToRoute = null)
    {
        if (! $request->user() ||
            ($request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&
            ! $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail())) {

            return $request->expectsJson()
                    ? abort(403, 'Your email address is not verified.')
                    : Redirect::route($redirectToRoute ?: 'verification.notice');
        }

        if (session()->has('url_intended')) {
            $redirectURL = session()->get('url_intended');
            session()->forget('url_intended');
            return redirect($redirectURL);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

its working like charm.
Update: simply create new middleware based on existing EnsureEmailIsVerified middleware, and attach it to Kernel.php :

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //other middlewares here..
    'verified' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the filter is handled at the routes level, then its so simple since you just need to attach an `auth` middleware to your original link. When a user successfully pass through the middleware check (means they login), they are automatically redirected to the intended destination. For example, you can do this instead of checking authentication in the controller

```
Route::get('/appointments',[AppointmentsController::class,'appointments'])->middleware(['auth'])->name('appointments');
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this in your routes.php ?

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //
    Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
       // Also place this code into base controller in contract function,            because ever controller extends base  controller
 if(Auth::id) {
  //here redirect your code or function
 }
if (Auth::guest()) {
       return Redirect::guest('login');
}
```

Comment: Please provide some commentary to go along with your code to provide some context. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**For Laravel 5.2** (previous versions I did not use)

Paste the code into the file app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AurhController.php

```
   /**
 * Overrides method in class 'AuthenticatesUsers'
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function showLoginForm()
{
    $view = property_exists($this, 'loginView')
        ? $this->loginView : 'auth.authenticate';
    if (view()->exists($view)) {
        return view($view);
    }
    /**
     * seve the previous page in the session
     */
    $previous_url = Session::get('_previous.url');
    $ref = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
    $ref = rtrim($ref, '/');
    if ($previous_url != url('login')) {
        Session::put('referrer', $ref);
        if ($previous_url == $ref) {
            Session::put('url.intended', $ref);
        }
    }
    /**
     * seve the previous page in the session
     * end
     */
    return view('auth.login');
}
/**
 * Overrides method in class 'AuthenticatesUsers'
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $throttles
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
protected function handleUserWasAuthenticated(Request $request, $throttles)
{
    if ($throttles) {
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
    }
    if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated')) {
        return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->user());
    }
    /*return to the previous page*/
    return redirect()->intended(Session::pull('referrer'));
    /*return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath()); /*Larevel default*/
}
```

And import namespace: `use Session;`

If you have not made any changes to the file app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AurhController.php, you can just replace it with the file from the [GitHub](https://github.com/zdorovoveselo/Laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login)

Answer (score -1):

## Laravel 5.2

If you are using a another Middleware like **Admin** middleware you can set a session for *url.intended* by using this following:

Basically we need to set manually `\Session::put('url.intended', \URL::full());` for redirect.

**Example**

```
  if (\Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
      if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
         return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
      } else {
        \Session::put('url.intended', \URL::full());
        return redirect('login');
      }
  }
```

**On login attempt**

Make sure on login attempt use `return \Redirect::intended('default_path');`

Comment: That's what `redirect()->guest('login')` is for.

Answer (score -1):

**Larvel 5.3**  this actually worked for me by just updating LoginController.php

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    Session::set('backUrl', URL::previous());
}


public function redirectTo()
{
    return Session::get('backUrl') ? Session::get('backUrl') :   $this->redirectTo;
}
```

ref: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/redirect-to-previous-page-after-login

Answer (score -1):

For Laravel 5.7, You need to make change into:

> Middleware>RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

Change this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/admin');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

To this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/yourpath');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

> **return redirect('/yourpath');**

Comment: What is `mypath` ? ( user pass for back to this)

Answer (score -1):

**I am using the following approach with a custom login controller and middleware for Laravel 5.7, but I hope that works in any of laravel 5 versions**

- inside middleware

  ```
  if (Auth::check()){
      return $next($request);
  }
  else{
    return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
  }
  ```
- inside controller login method

  ```
  if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
  return redirect()->intended('/default');
  }
  ```
- If you need to pass the intented url to **client side**, you can try the following

  ```
     if (Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password])) {
         $intended_url= redirect()->intended('/default')->getTargetUrl();
         $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'redirectUrl' => $intended_url,
        'message' => 'Login successful.you will be redirected to home..', );
        return response()->json($response);
      } else {
          $response = array(
        'status' => 'failed',
        'message' => 'username or password is incorrect', );
       return response()->json($response);
      }
  ```

Answer (score -1):

First, you should know, how you redirect user to 'login' route:

```
return redirect()->guest('/signin');
```

Not like this:

```
return redirect()->intended('/signin');
```