# how to redirect particular page after login in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-4

I want to redirect the user for particular page after successful login.

I don't want the user to navigate to the last viewed page after login.

I have tried following url but its show me error.

**Error:**

> `$credentials` are required.

[Laravel redirect back to original destination after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389833/laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login)

Comment: Why not use `Redirect::route('route-name)`?

Comment: can you post some code, how you are redirecting after login

Comment: down vote please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed redirect page using following code after login

Previous

```
return Redirect::intended('home');
```

Change to

```
return Redirect::to('home');
```

Comment: In what method did you do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add auth filter to your route and add logic to redirect user if login is success or failure.

Your route will look something like:

```
Route::group(array('domain'=>'a.b.com', 'before'=>'auth'), function() {
```

and your filter will be like:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::user()->guest())
    {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('account/login');
        }
    }
});
```

Have a look [here](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=10653) for adding route and filter, and [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters) to get basic information regarding filter. These 2 tutorials will also help:
[Link 1](http://culttt.com/2013/09/09/registration-authentication-laravel-4/) & [Link 2](http://culttt.com/2013/09/16/use-laravel-4-filters/)

In your AccountController, try to add something inside validate function:

```
if (Session::has('url.intended')) {
 $url = Session::get('url.intended');
 Session::forget('url.intended');   // unset referring url from session 
 return Redirect::to($url); // redirect to referring url
}
else {
    return Redirect::to('/');   // redirect to home page
}
```

Comment: In my filter i have following code "Route::filter('auth', function()
{
 if (Auth::guest())
 {
  if (Request::ajax())
  {
   return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
  }
  else
  {
   return Redirect::guest('')->with('Message', 'Please Login to get Access');
  }
 }
});"

Comment: Okay, that's great but what are you trying to say?

Comment: its redirect last view page after login

Comment: I have updated my answer, try to do something like that.

Answer (score -2):

Customize redirect location by defining a redirectPath property on the Auth/AuthController:

```
protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard';
```

Comment: that not works, after login laravel try to go to last page, i means if you refresh your last page on sistem(loged on sistem) and your session is out. the laravel send you to login and after login its send you to your last page, no to $redirectpath.