# Laravel redirect back after login

Tags: php, laravel

How can I redirect back page after login? in Laravel 5.2

AuthController

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

RedirectUsers

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

trait RedirectsUsers
{
    /**
     * Get the post register / login redirect path.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function redirectPath()
    {
        if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath')) {
            return $this->redirectPath;
        }

        return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/';
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add `return redirect()->back()` in the login function, that's it. Just make sure you don't end up in a redirect loop, it happens.

Comment: @Andrew
Where I add that code on? I used make:auth in Laravel 5.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954791/laravel-5-after-login-redirect-back-to-previous-page/56095470#56095470 Refer to this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using either of these two options.

- return Redirect::back(); This will take the user back to the page from where he/she came.
- return redirect('enter your route here'); This will take the user to the view which you have defined with that particular route.

Comment: Where I add that code on? I used make:auth in Laravel 5.2

Answer (score 0):

In your auth function which you've written in the controller. It'll be something like this:

```
 function xyz() {

  // your function code

  return Redirect::back();
}
```