# Redirect after login laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I want to redirect the user after login to '/details'..but it redirect me to '/home'

LoginController.php

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('/details');
        }
        return redirect('/details');

    }
```

RouterServiceProvider.php

```
public const HOME = '/details';
```

I've tried this.but still can't do it

> [Laravel redirect back after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39770231/laravel-redirect-back-after-login)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default In your LoginController just replace

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

TO

```
protected $redirectTo = '/details';
```

But if you use own authenticate so you use like this

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
        //return redirect()->intended('/details');
    }
    return redirect($this->redirectPath());

}
```

Comment: @HilaryOkoro It's working fine for me and others three who use this follow this instruction. So please check your code and review. Check this link also

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61754023/laravel-redirect-to-login-page-after-successful-verification?noredirect=1#comment109234612_61754023

Answer (score 3):

In your Auth\LoginController.php, you can override the function used after login :

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    return redirect()->route('route.name');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Laravel 7**

Can use `authenticated` function in these ways:

**1. Change Original Function**

original `authenticated` function is stored in `vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php`, change it like below:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->is_superuser) {
        return redirect('/admin');
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

**2. Overwrite**

in `LogniController` stored in `app/Http/Controllers/LoginController.php` paste top function.

**Tip:** `is_superuser` is a boolean field in users table and shows that a user is admin (superuser) or not.

Answer (score 0):

Go to RouteServiceProvider.php file and change the route from '/home'to what you want.