# Laravel Redirect To Login Page After Successful Verification

Tags: laravel, email-verification

I implements `MustVerifyEmail` to verify registered user. What I want is it will redirect to login page after successful verification by email. Trying to do this, but still, it keep redirect to /home.

**VerificationController.php**

```
class VerificationController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Email Verification Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling email verification for any
    | user that recently registered with the application. Emails may also
    | be re-sent if the user didn't receive the original email message.
    |
    */

    use VerifiesEmails;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after verification.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        //generate URL dynamicaly .
        return '/login'; // return dynamicaly generated URL.
    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to write verify method in this controller.Then you redirect what you want

Comment: Yes, I did! I override `verify` method from `VerifiesEmails` and place it at `VerificationController.php`, but still... doesn't work. Any solution?

Comment: You follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61385990/redirect-after-login-laravel-7/61388367#61388367

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I followed your answer. I made `return redirect()->intended('/');`, that's work, it was redirect to welcome page. But still login. I want the user logout automatically after he clicked verification link address.

Comment: you have to session destroy or AuthLogout

Comment: It work's! Big clue! Many thanks!

Comment: You are most welcome @Sead Lab

Answer (score 0):

return view('/');
or try php artisan config:cache