# Laravel - Redirect user to previous page after successful login

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5.7

I am trying to redirect the user back to the previous page after a successful login. For that, in the `LoginController.php` I added a `redirectTo()` function as such :

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
   return url()->previous();
}
```

With this in place, I tried logging in but after successful login, I am redirected to the home page.(`/`).

When I did `dd(url()->previous())` in the `redirectTo()` function, I found the previous URL was `http://localhost/login`. So the user was redirected to `login` page which then redirected to `home` page.

I also tried `return redirect()->back()` in the `redirectTo()` function but I got the following error

> Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

I also tried using `authenticate()` in the `LoginController`

```
public function authenticate()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

It redirects to `/home`(Which is not found)
Using `return redirect()->intended()` instead of `return redirect()->back()` gives the same result.

**How Do I redirect the user to the previous page in which he/she was when he/she accessed the login page?**

*I still want to retain the default functionality that when a user tries to access a route with `auth` Middlewate, he is taken to login page and after successful login, redirected to the page where he intended to go in the first place.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - After login redirect back to previous page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954791/laravel-5-after-login-redirect-back-to-previous-page)

Answer (score 2):

```
Redirect::back()
back()
redirect()->back()
redirect()->previous()
```

are the same and they get you to the previous page.
what you can do is send a return url as a parameter or put it in a session, when your authentication is done, redirect to that url.

```
redirect()->to($request->input('returnUrl'))
```

For the redirection to home, it is hard coded in "App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php"

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

You should also read about trait in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I worked in the following way :

In LoginController

```
public function redirectTo(){
    if (request()->has('previous')) {
        $this->redirectTo = request()->get('previous');
    }
    return $this->redirectTo ?? '/defaultPath';
}
```

The method `request()->has('previous')` verify if exists previus path in session, if not exist redirect to default path.

Answer (score 0):

You may do so by using the global back helper function.

```
return back()->withInput();
```

Comment: Where should I add this ?

Comment: back() returns you to google window where to choose a google user

Answer (score 0):

Just add to LoginController

```
 public function redirectTo(){
    if (request()->has('previous')) {
        $this->redirectTo = request()->get('previous');
    }
    return $this->redirectTo ?? '/defaultPath';
}
```