# How laravel redirects to the before auth page after login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am using Laravel 5.

I have tried to access the following url

```
http:://localhost/myproject/public/index.php/tasks
```

I have added my `App/Controllers/Controller.php` as following code

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

This code will redirects to login page whenever I try to access any pages in project. That will redirects to the same page which I have tried to access after login. I don't know how laravel doing this. Can anybody tell how this is working?

Comment: define them on `Route`

Comment: I don't know what you are saying

Comment: use something like this `Entrust::routeNeedsRole('your prefix/*', 'your_role', Redirect::to('/'));`

Comment: Shall we talk briefly?

Comment: I am using entrust for permission check... I need to check Entrust::can('my pprefix/*', 'my-permission', Redirect::to('auth/login'));

This will perfectly redirects to login page... But what I need is after login this must redirect to the page I have entered before

For Example... i try to access `http://laravel/project` This will redirect to login page. After login I need to redirect to the same `http://laravel/project'`page if the user has permission.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel redirect back to original destination after login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389833/laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login)

Comment: Have you tried to implement before/after middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create following function in `AuthController`. This function will override same function in `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait. Now you can modify its code to redirect to desired location.

```
/**
 * Get the post register / login redirect path.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath'))
    {
        return $this->redirectPath;
    }

    return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/';
}
```