# laravel redirect to url after login

Tags: laravel, redirect, authentication

I have trouble with redirecting to an url after login.
The situation is that someone visits a blog post, and needs to login before adding a comment. So the user clicks on the login link and logs in on "auth/login", and is always redirected to "/home".

I want the user to be redirected to the blogpost when an url is set like "auth/login?redirect=url/to/blogpost"

I have the following Middleware:

**app\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389833/laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to copy and paste the **getLogin** function of the trait AuthenticatesUsers into my AuthController. I overwrite the function AND keep the trait as is.

I've just added

`\Session::put('url.intended',\URL::previous());`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the intended method on redirector? Read about this in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users)

> The intended method on the redirector will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being caught by the authentication filter. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the intended destination is not available.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using standard authentication from Laravel 5, find a `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php` file and change `$redirectPath` to this:

```
protected $redirectPath = '/url/to/blogpost';
```