# how to change laravel's Authcontroller's redirect path to last URL(back)

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and it want to change the Authcontroller's "$redirectTo" variable's path to back().I mean after user logs in they must be redirected back to from where they have came not to the home page.I tried many thing like setting it to,

```
protected $redirectTo=Redirect::back();
protected $redirectTo=redirect->back();
```

but nothing worked.I dont want to create my custom authenction system thats why i used "php artisan make:auth" for authentication system.Please help.Thanks

Comment: Many good answers that will fullfill your needs : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389833/laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login

Comment: Thnaks, I read it but as i said i am using default "make:auth" command so there are only four middleware's .Authencticate is one of them i don't know where to past that code. I tried by pasting it in Authenticate.php controller but that didn't worked.