# Laravel save user page after login

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have a problem. When guest is on the page, and want login. Laravel redirect on main page after login. How I can do, when guest login save page where he was and redirect there?

Middleware auth:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated {
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (!Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect()->guest('/login');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

I use default auth laravel. But back on previous page after login not working.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36695762/laravel-5-2-redirect-to-intended-url-after-login

Comment: Is it a double redirect? Meaning first firing a redirect to the login page and then redirecting to the main page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the original question was for Socialite and was later modified to the default auth, I will address both here.

**1. Laravel Socialite**

Laravel Socialite intended redirects dont work the way people expect them to because the first redirect is from the controller for the authentication.

Here's what you need to do.

In your `redirectToProvider` method, add this:

```
if(!session()->has('url.intended')) {
    session()->put('url.intended', url()->previous());
}
```

Then, in your `handleProviderCallback` method, add this:

```
if(session()->has('url.intended')) {
    $redirectUrl = session('url.intended');
} else {
    $redirectUrl = 'your fallback url here';
}
session()->forget('url.intended');
return redirect($redirectUrl);
```

**2. Default Authentication If You Have a Separate Login Page**

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    // Authentication passed...
    return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
}
```

**3. Default Authentication If You Do Not Have a Separate Login Page**

What this means is that perhaps you have a modal window on each page for a login and so, there's no separate page for login per se and each page can perform a post request for login.

```
$redirectUrl = session('url.intended', url()->previous());
session()->forget('url.intended');
return redirect($redirectUrl);
```

Comment: But default laravel auth?

Comment: But where I can write code on login page. If I have only auth/login.blade ? But controller auth use laravel

Comment: If you have a separate blade template for login, case #2 applies. You need to add that code to the post route method for login. It should work out of the box

Comment: In my routes I didn't have post login method. I use default auth laravel. I edit only template for login.blade and all. This is default laravel auth: `Auth::login`

Comment: In your LoginController, add a `protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)` and add the code in case #2. That should do the trick

Comment: undefined variable email, password? Where I can get email and password?

Comment: Just add this in the authenticated method: `return redirect()->intended('dashboard');`

Comment: And I redirect on dashboard, but I have more pages, and example guest on: /cart page, how I can redirect on cart or other pages?

Comment: When the guest tries to go to the cart page if unauthenticated, is he/she redirected to the login page first?

Comment: Yes. He redirect on login page