# Laravel: Redirect different user roles differently

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

Is it possible to redirect users with different user roles to a different page in laravel 5.1?

I have looked into Auth middleware and Auth controller, but found nothing that processes the login request itself.

I have found something about login redirection here [Laravel redirect back to original destination after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389833/laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login) but i'm not sure where to put the suggested code snippets.

Can someone help me out

Comment: Would be a task of recreating/overriding the `AuthController` to handle the login differently, or writing a new middleware to handle redirection of a newly logged in user to the appropriate page based on their role. Question is a little too broad for SO purposes though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update in RedirectIfAuthenticated Middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->check()) {

            $auth = Auth::user()->roles()->first();

            switch ($auth->role) {
                case 'admin':
                        return  redirect()->route('admin');    
                    break;
                case 'superadmin':
                        return  redirect()->route('superadmin'); 
                    break;
                case 'user':
                        return  redirect()->route('user');  
                    break;

                default:
                    # code...
                    return  redirect()->route('user');  
                    break;
            }   

         }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: can't believe i missed that file in middleware