# How to redirect guest to login page, after redirect back after login in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I use php artisan `make:auth` function in Laravel 5.2.

I want to redirect guest to login page if guest clicks link that only for user not guest.

And I want to redirect users to back page after login.

How can I do this? Please show some examples with file name in detail.

///////edit

Route

```
// Routes for logged in users
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
//write
Route::get('board/create', ['as' => 'board.create', 'uses' =>'BoardController@create']);
});
```

Controller

```
public function create() {

    return view('board.create');

}
```

Kernel.php

Comment: Take a look at this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15393229/4199784

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel redirect back to original destination after login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389833/laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is achieved using Middleware. By default the `App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated` and the `\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate` middleware are loaded. (Check your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file to check which middleware are loaded.

So with route groups :

```
// Routes for anyone
Route::get('guest-or-user', 'SomeController@action');

// Routes for guests only
Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function() {
    Route::get('user-not-logged-in', 'SomeController@guestAction');
});

// Routes for logged in users
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('user-logged-in', 'SomeController@userAction');
    // ... other routes
});
```

You can also do this in your controller:

```
// SomeController.php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['only' => 'guestAction']);
    $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => 'userAction']);
}

public function action()
{
    // ...
}

public function guestAction()
{
    // ...
}


public function userAction()
{
    // ...
}
```

Read the doc: [Protecting Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#protecting-routes)

Comment: sorry for check lately, I edit my question

Comment: Where can I define my BoardController in Kernel.php ?

Comment: You don't need to add anything to `Kernel.php` if you're using built-in middleware like `auth` and `guest` which are already added in your `app/Http/Kernel.php`

Comment: can I use controller like this ?

Comment: class BoardController extends Controller
{
 public function __construct()
 {
     $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => 'create']);
 }

public function create() {

  return view('board.create');
 
 }
}

Comment: Yes you can. Though you've already stated in your routes file that you're protecting the `BoardController@create` action so it's not necessary to add it in the controller's `__construct` method too.

Comment: thank u for comments !

Comment: umm.. The codes not working, url is changed but nothing happend. TT

Comment: What's the url now? Show your routes and controller please

Comment: url is borad/create. and my related routes and controller is on my edit question.

Comment: Can u try this in your controller and show the result : `public function create() {
    dd(auth()->user());

    return view('board.create');

}`

Comment: same, nothing happened

Comment: It shows just before page that click button.<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" aria-expanded="false" onclick="location.href='{{route('board.create')}}' ">글쓰기</button>