# laravel 5 redirect to previous page after sign in

Tags: php, session, authentication, laravel-5

laravel 5 redirect to previous page after sign in.

When I am hitting a url manually if its not logged in its redrecting to login page but after login it should redirect to url which entered but in my case its going to home page.

Code:

```
public function index()
    { 

            // Is the user logged in?
        if (Auth::check()) 
        { 
            return Redirect::route('dashboard');
        }

        // Show the page
        return View('auth.login');
    }


public function getSignin()
    { 

            // Is the user logged in?
        if (Auth::check()) 
        { 
            return Redirect::route('dashboard');
        }

        // Show the page
        return View('auth.login');
    }
```

Comment: Or should i change Middleware ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel redirect back to original destination after login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389833/laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login)

Answer (score 1):

In `LoginController` and `RegisterController`, replace the field `$redirectTo` with the following:

```
protected function redirectTo(){
    return url()->previous();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `redirect()->back()` in case if the user is logged in

Comment: redirect()->back(); wont work as the previous url will be login page and if its goes to login page as its already logged it it will redirect to home page...

Comment: you can find your answer here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389833/laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: without using middelware can we do this ??

Comment: try to use this replace ` return Redirect::route('dashboard');` with `return Redirect::intended('dashboard');` 
`