# Setting session variables in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, session, laravel-5.4

I have a feeling this is a very dumb question and there's probably something really tiny I just overlooked, but I'm stumped anyway.

Currently, I have an app with a few pages that are protected through middleware. If the user does not meet the requirements of these middleware, they are redirected to a login page. Now after they log in, I want them to be sent back to the page they tried to visit.

I've tried numerous things to accomplish this, but none work. What I'm trying to do now is the following:

1. User attempts to access an admin page (for example */admin*): PagesController@adminDashboard
2. When they access the overview() method in the controller (same as index(), but for admins), a session variable is set containing the url they tried to visit (*/admin*)
3. The user is redirected to the login page and logs in (SessionsController@create and @store)
4. After logging in, they are redirected to the session variable with the intended URL

This is how I tried to do it:

---

PagesController

```
public function adminDashboard()
{
    $intended = '/admin';
    session('intended-url', $intended);

    //dd(session('intended-url');

    $schools = School::all();
    $articles = Article::all();
    $sights = Sight::all();

    return view('admin', compact('sights', 'articles', 'schools'));
}
```

SessionsController

```
public function store()
{
    /*
        ...
    */

    $intendedURL = session('intended-url');

    if($intendedURL != null)
    {
        return redirect($intendedURL);
    }
    else
    {
        return redirect()->home();
    }
```

---

Using dd() a few times here and there, I found out that it doesn't even set the session variable at the very start (commented dd() in PagesController returns null).

I've tried doing this using Session::put(), Session::set(), using square brackets as in session(['intended-url', '/admin']), but none of it gives me the result I'm looking for :(

Does anyone have any advice on how to do this, or perhaps a different way of accomplishing the same goal, but more efficiently? Thank you!

EDIT: I don't think the default Laravel redirect to intended page will work here, since I rewrote most of the login system from scratch to suit some specific needs. Unless anyone knows how that redirect works behind the scenes and I can over-/rewrite it

Comment: This should be built into laravel 5.4 If you are using the laravels default auth. have you checked it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel redirect back to original destination after login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389833/laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login)

Comment: To set a session variable using the helper method you should first do session(['key' => 'value']); and then get the variable. Your calls to the session helper seem to be wrong for setting the variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default auth system, you can use this to redirect users to the page they wanted to view:

```
return redirect()->intended('fallback/uri');
```

Comment: I'm afraid I've rewritten the login system from scratch and disabled or deleted most of Laravel's defaults... We needed a much more advanced system than Laravel's and if I kept in the old routes and controllers, there were too many conflicts

Sorry for the complications :(

Answer (score 0):

why u are not using middleware just make new middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware admin
```

and add this code of public function handle

```
if (!Auth::guest() && Auth::user()->admin) {

        return $next($request);
    }
     return redirect('/')->with('warning', 'This Area only For Admin');
```

add this code in kernal on protected $routeMiddleware

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\admin::class,
];
```

make new column in users table

```
$table->boolean('admin')->default(false);
```

now you can use your construct function

```
 public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('admin');
}
```

Note:- where u add  $this->middleware('admin'); all controller will be locked for users and guest only admin can use this controller

Comment: While I appreciate your answer, as I said, I've already implemented some middleware for 5 different roles, and that's all working as it should be.

The only problem now is the redirection

Comment: oh i understand than you can use if else attributes help of session like if you are admin check if(auth:user()->admin && auth:user()->mod) { //your code with redirect session } else Your are user or guest