# Redirect to home page if I already login in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-middleware

I want to redirect login page to home page when i already login. At the same time when I hit login route, it show me login page. I have made custom login page. Where I need to change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel redirect back to original destination after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389833/laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login)

Comment: Thanks . but what is the file name which I have to change?

Answer (score 2):

You should put your login route into `guest` middleware something like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {

    // Authentication Routes...
    Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');

});
```

and in `app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` you can define where user should be redirected in such case if you don't want to use defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Check `Auth::user()` condition in that

```
if(Auth::user())
//home page
else
//login page
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Asyou can read in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#included-authenticating) you can set a custom redirect path directly in Login- ,Register- and ResetPasswordController in `App\Http\Controllers\Auth`.

Simply add protected $redirectTo = 'your/custom/path'; to the top of the controller. In your case it should be the `LoginController`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = 'your/redirect/path';

    // other stuff...
}
```

This should work for already logged in users as well as for not-logged-in users.