# Laravel redirect to previous page after login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, redirect

I use default laravel auth. In `LoginController` I have constuct:

```
public function __construct()
{
    session(['url.intended' => url()->previous()]);
    //dd(session()->get('url.intended'));
    $this->redirectTo = session()->get('url.intended');
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
```

But redirect after login not working.
Example: I have page cart, when I guest, I redirect to login from page cart. But session for some reason is main.page (/), when I do `dd(session()->get('url.intended'))`. Why? In Cart controller I use: `$user = Auth::user();`.

Page login: `site.com/login`

Middleware:

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389833/laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389833/laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login) You can find the answer in this page.

Comment: Could use `Redirect::back()`

Comment: not working :((!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you login, capture the HTTP_REFERER header.

```
Request::server('HTTP_REFERER').
```

Then redirect to it.

```
return redirect()->to($referer);
```

Comment: what if the referer was a facebook link, this will redirect the user back to facebook