# Laravel Redirect user to original destination after login

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel app I have a private page which can be only accessed by Auth users. I am also using social logins, so when a user goes to private page without logging in, Laravel sends user to login page and after successful login, the user is sent back to original destination (private page). Only when a user logs in via Laravel inbuilt Auth system, but when a user logs in via the Social Login method, the user will be directed to the homepage.

This is my Social Login handler after login:

```
public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{

    $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();

    $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
    Auth::login($authUser, true);
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

How can I send the user to the original destination if it's present in session, otherwise send them back to home.

Comment: `return redirect()->intended('/home');` Use built in laravel intended method

Comment: @Saad Suri Thanks its working :) have a nice day

Comment: Posting it as an answer so future readers can get help

Comment: It's a duplicate question - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389833/laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use,

```
return redirect()->intended('/home')
```

The intended method on the redirector will redirect the user to the URL they were attempting to access before being intercepted by the authentication middleware. A fallback URI may be given to this method in case the intended destination is not available.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#authenticating-users) mentions it very briefly, but Laravel has a built-in method:

```
return redirect()->intended('/home')
```

Whenever the Auth middleware redirects a user because he is not logged in, his original url will be stored. `intended` checks whether or not that url is stored and uses that, or the fallback you supply as argument.