# How to Redirect Previous page in laravel after session logout?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Where can i write its logic in my file ? below are my login function.

```
public function login( Request $request ) 
{ 
    $this->validate( $request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if( Auth::guard('employee')->attempt( [
        'email' => $request->input( 'email' ),
        'password' => $request->input( 'password' ),
        'status'=>'Active'
    ]) ) {  
        return redirect('/employee/dashboard');
    } else {
        return view('employee.login')->withErrors( [ 'email' => 'Authentication failed' ] );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can look through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389833/laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel redirect back to original destination after login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389833/laravel-redirect-back-to-original-destination-after-login)