# Redirect to previous page after login laravel5.7

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, redirect, laravel-5.7

I am working on a requirement where I send emails after record update/insert in which I send page URL as "click here" text, when user clicks on that link he will be redirected to that page regardless of user logs in or not.

Now if the user already logged-in then that page normally opens but if user is not logged-in then  I need to redirect back to previous page after login.

**My Problem here is** I am unable to redirect back to the previous page which user tried to access before login through 'click here' link from email

I have searched for the solutions I found few but they were not working. One of the solution I tried is [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39595605/908579) but din't work why because our application authentication is totally customized. Our RedirectIfAuthenticated file code is below

**NOTE:** Our application has been built on Laravel

RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
  {
    $path = $request->path();
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        if($path == 'app1')
        {
            return redirect('/app1/dashboard');
        }
        elseif($path == 'app2')
        {
            return redirect('/app2/dashboard');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: are you use ajax?

Comment: return redirect()->route('route_name'); ?

Comment: what is 'route_name' in my case?

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is get the previous URL and check with that and redirect to relevant dashboard you can use `URL::previous()` in `URL` Facades. you can do something like this,

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
   public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
   {
      $path1 = url('app1/login')
      $path2 = url('app2/login')

      if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        if($path1 == URL::previous())
        {
           return redirect('/app1/dashboard');
        }
        elseif($path2 == URL::previous())
        {
            return redirect('/app2/dashboard');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
  } 
}
```

Hope this helps. if you just want check *app1* or *app2* I suggest that you `explode()` the `previous()` and check

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to redirect on back page

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
  {
    $path = $request->path();
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect()->back();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As I said our application is customized, it has 2 separate applications merged into one so, if user tried to login via app1/login then will be redirected to app1/dashboard or else redirected to app2/dashboard from app1/login.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

override this method in `Auth\LoginController`

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
     if ($request->expectsJson() || $request->ajax()) {
        // return login success in json
     }
     return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Eg. if you are trying to access `/user/send/email` and the user is not logged in then it will redirect to `login` page once the user is logged in then it will automatically redirect to `/user/send/email` page

**RedirectIfAuthenticated**

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
     public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
     {
         $path = $request->path();
         if ( auth()->guard($guard)->check() ) {
            return redirect()->route($path.'.dashboard');
            // or
            // return redirect()->route($guard.'.dashboard'); //Suggest: define route based on guard
        }
        return $next($request);
     }

}
```

Register route as `app1.dashboard` and `app2.dashboard`

Answer (score 0):

Store the path in session variable, if the user is not logged in. After successful login, check if the session value is set,  redirect the user to the value set and before redirecting the user do not forget to unset the session

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
        $path = $request->path(); 
        $url = "";
        if($path == 'app1')
        {
           $url="/app1/dashboard";             
         }
        elseif($path == 'app2')
        {
           $url="/app2/dashboard";             
        }

        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
              return redirect($url);
        }
        else{
          // create session variable and store the path 
          // save `$url` to session variable
        }

      return $next($request);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try & get back.

Comment: but you understand the logic right? storing the path in session and redirection based on the value set

Comment: I have understood partially. I will store the url to session and where to use that session? in login page or where?

Comment: yes, when the login is successfully just add a check that if the session is set, get the path and redirect.. and before writing redirect line, unset that session